# How do I import modules from an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-import

Im trying to import a set of modules that are defined by an array. The reason I would like to store them in an array is because I would like to change this list dynamically.

```
moduleNames = ['sys', 'os']
import moduleNames
```

However this doesnt work.

I have searched around and found this:

```
moduleNames = ['sys', 'os']
modules = map(__inport__, moduleNames)
```

This imports the modules however I would like to be able to access it by doing `sys.version` for example. Rather than by using `modules[0].version`

Is this currently possible I can't seem to find anywhere that shows you how to do it.

Comment: Your rationale make no sense. How does the rest of your code know that a module named `sys` was imported (so it knows to use `sys.version`)?

Comment: I don't know that's why I asked the question. Its now resolved so don't worry about my rationale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
for m in modules:
    globals()[m] = __import__(m)
```